# AngularJS directive to create a thumbnail

Tags: angularjs

I've just started learning AngularJS and I'm approaching directives. I'd need to create a directive named f.e. "thumbnail" which takes as input a "src" (the image) and create a thumbnail of it.
So far I've coded the javascript function to create the thumbnail which does its job correctly:

```
function readURL(input) {

var imageSize = 50;

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {

        var blah = $('#myimage');
        blah.attr('src', e.target.result);

        var height = blah.height();
        var width = blah.width();

        if (height < imageSize && width < imageSize) {
            if (width > height) {
                blah.width(imageSize);
            }
            else {
                blah.height(imageSize)
            }
        }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
</script>
<body  onload="readURL(this);">
<img id="myimage" src="../picture.gif" width="50" alt="your image" />
```

However I have not been able to find a simple example which produces (in AngularJS) an Element, based on a JS function. Any help ? 
Thanks!

Comment: FileReader is not available in IE8/9 So if those are in your target-audience be sure to include a polyfill for it.

Comment: In my application I just use `<img ng-src="{{dataUrl}}">` And have the form controller set the dataUrl in the scope when a file is added.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If your purpose of creating a thumbnail at client-side is to:

1. **Upload in a smaller size** in a *web application*: perhaps you can make use of a library like http://www.plupload.com.
2. **Display only**: you should just use CSS resizing with `width` and `height` properties.

   `<img src="/original/320x320.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">`
3. **Reading/storing in an [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)/PhoneGap app**: try make use of [angular-thumbnail](https://github.com/kennyki/angular-thumbnail) (disclaimer: I wrote it)

Answer (score 0):

Doing image manipulation of this kind on the client side is not a very good idea , because, as of now there isn't a good support for [Filereader](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader) in IE.

You can delegate this either to server(you will find lot of node module for image manipulation) or you can use external services like [cloudinay](http://cloudinary.com/)